# Migrate files from one esb to other

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have created few proxies, sequences and endpoints in wso2 esb in my system. I want to transfer these proxies, sequences and endpoints to another esb hosted at server. How to do this successfully?
Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have your first ESB located at ESB01_HOME directory and it contains all your defined proxy services, endpoints and other configurations. Now you took another fresh copy of the WSO2 ESB and extract that to a folder called ESB02_HOME.

You can copy the configuration files which were stored in ESB01_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default (entire folder) in to the same directory in the ESB02 (ESB02_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default). Now you can start the ESB02 and you can observe that all the configurations are installed in the ESB02.

If you are starting both the servers (ESB01 and ESB02), then you need to change the Offset parameter of the ESB02 carbon.xml configuration file which is located in the (ESB02_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml)

If you are copying the configurations from an older version of WSO2 ESB (3.x.x) then these configurations are located at ESB01_HOME/repository/conf/synapse-configs folder.

Answer (score 1):

If both are in a clustered setup you can use deployment synchronizer/registry based synchronizer..If both are separate instances, copy the synapse-config folder(inside that, you can find proxy/seq/endpoint folders) to another home directpry

Answer (score 1):

you can use the checkin-client tool inside the GREG. 
With this tool you can move information from registry in ESB1 to registry in ESB2. information like dynamic sequences and endpoints for example.